# has and belongs to more than 1 table

Tags: ruby, has-many, attr, has-and-belongs-to-many, accessible

I have an scaffold (`critical_factor`) with some fields like `catalog_table_id` and `selectRight` and also other scaffold (`catalog_table`) with the fields name `table_name`, `model`.

When I select in the `critical_factor` view in the field `catalog_table_id` the `selectRight` fill with all the fields of the table selected.

I have a `has_and_belong_to catalog_tables_critical_factors` with the fields `catalog_table_id`, `critical_factor_id` and `table_relation_fields_id`. In the last field I want save the `id` from the `selectRight` in the `critical_factor` view but I am only able to save the first two fields.

Any ideas?

**Critical Factor Model**

```
class CriticalFactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :catalog_tables
  attr_accessible: :critical_factor_id,:selectRight, :catalog_table_id
  def selectRight=(options)
    self.catalog_tables.clear
    options.each do |option|
      unless option.empty?
        line = CatalogTable.find(catalog_table_id)
        modelo = line.model
        case modelo
          when 'ActivityTypes'
            line = ActivityType.find(options,options.id)
          when 'Programs'
            line = Program.find(options)
        end

        self.catalog_tables << line
      end
    end
end
```

**Catalog Table Model**

```
class CatalogTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :critical_factors
  attr_accessible :name, :model, :table
end
```

**catalog_table_critical_factor model**

```
class CatalogTablesCriticalFactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :critical_factor_id, :catalog_table_id, :table_select_field_id
end
```